# _ViewStart stops working after creating a razor custom view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've created a razor custom view engine that extends RazorViewEngine. Then suddenly I'm unable to access the variables I've defined in _ViewStart.cshtml at the /Views folder, which normally work on a default project initialized by VS2010 MVC3 template.

My question is how to enable _ViewStart in a razor custom view engine?

Comment: I know this question is old.  Generally speaking, it would be helpful to see some code or to know what you overrode when you extended the Razor view engine.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code I can't specifically say what's going wrong, but after viewing [the source](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/7fe40652f0660896b914aa75b567cced3bdce539#src/System.Web.Mvc/RazorViewEngine.cs) the for the `RazorViewEngine` I think may have an idea what you are not doing.

This is what the `CreateView` method looks like:

```
    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
        var view = new RazorView(controllerContext, viewPath,
                                 layoutPath: masterPath, runViewStartPages: true, viewStartFileExtensions: FileExtensions, viewPageActivator: ViewPageActivator)
        {
            DisplayModeProvider = DisplayModeProvider
        };
        return view;
    }
```

You can see they are passing a value of `true` in for the `runViewStartPages` argument on the `RazorView` constructor.  Looking at [the source](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/7fe40652f0660896b914aa75b567cced3bdce539#src/System.Web.Mvc/RazorView.cs) of the `RenderView` method in the `RazorView` class reveals that this boolean parameter is used to create a `StartPageLookupDelegate` that is responsible for finding the `_ViewStart` file and compile it into the execution hierarchy.

```
WebPageRenderingBase startPage = null;
if (RunViewStartPages)
{
    startPage = StartPageLookup(webViewPage, RazorViewEngine.ViewStartFileName, ViewStartFileExtensions);
}
webViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(new WebPageContext(context: viewContext.HttpContext, page: null, model: null), writer, startPage);
```

So this means you are likely doing one of two things:

1. Overriding the `CreateView` method of the `RazorViewEngine` and not initializing a `RazorView` in the manner listed above.
2. Overriding the `RenderView` method of the `RazorView` without creating a `StartPageLookupDelegate` and passing it into the `ExecutePageHierarchy` method.

Hopefully this helps send you down the correct path to finding a solution!